# Non- compact set

Tags: general-topology

We have to show that $$S = \lbrace (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : xy>1 , x^2 + y^2 < 5 \rbrace $$
is non-compact .

I tried taking an open cover $$x^2 + y^2 = 6$$ and then took countable subcover from it. but couldn't succeed further . Please help

Comment: $x^2 + y^2$ is an equation, not an open cover.  Do you understand what an open cover is?

Comment: Can you use Heine-Borel Theorem?

Comment: I dont know how to use that theorem.I have tried hard.

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb{R}^n$, compact is equivalent to closed and bounded. It suffices to show $S$ is not closed. Look at a sequence $(x_n,y_n) \in S$ tending to $(1,1) \notin S$.

Answer (score 0):

An idea:

Show that

$$\{x_n\}_{n\ge k\in\Bbb N}:=\left\{\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\;,\;\frac{2n+1}n\right)\right\}_{n\ge k\in\Bbb N}\subset S\;,\;\;\text{ for some}\;k\in\Bbb N$$

yet

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n\notin S$$

What does this prove?

Answer (score 0):

If $U_n=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:xy>1+n^{-1},x^2+y^2<5-n^{-1}\}$ for positive integers then the $U_n$ are open sets that cover $S$. There is no finite subcover, showing that $S$ is not compact.